# Adding double quotes around multiple variable string

Tags: bash, rhel

I need to add quote marks around the curlstring variable outputs at the bottom in bold. Any advice?

NOTE: There are other functions to this code but i've tried to make it as simple as possible

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -e -p "Would you like to get the access token? [Y/N]: " input

curlstring="curl"

read -r -e -p "Ignore cert errors? [Y/N]: " input
read -r -e -p "Would you like to add the HTTP verb?[Y/N]: " input
read -r -e -p "What is the Client ID? " clientid
read -r -e -p "What is the Grant Type? " granttype
read -r -e -p "What is the Client Secret? " clientsecret
read -r -e -p "What is the GUI username? " guiuser
read -r -e -p "And password of the user given above? " guipasswd
read -r -e -p "Whats the IP and Port number <ip:port>? " ipandport

curlstring=$curlstring" client_id="$clientid"&grant_type="$granttype"&client_secret="$clientsecret"&username="$guiuser"&password="$guipasswd" https://"$ipandport"/oauth/token"

echo "$curlstring"
```

My current output is

```
 curl -k -X POST -d client_id=stackoverflow&grant_type=testing&client_secret=372‌​ryc438t3948fj3u489f3‌​6&username=test&pass‌​word=testing 1.2.3.4:1111/oauth/token
```

however I want output like this

```
curl -k -X POST -d "client_id=stackoverflow&grant_type="testing"&client_secret‌​=372ryc438t3948fj3u‌​489f36&username=te‌​st&password=testin‌​g" 1.2.3.4:1111/oauth/token
```

Basically putting it in json format

**Having changed the code to**

```
read -r -e -p "Ignore cert errors? [Y/N]: " input
read -r -e -p "Would you like to add the HTTP verb?[Y/N]: " input
read -r -e -p "What is the Client ID? " clientid
read -r -e -p "What is the Grant Type? " granttype
read -r -e -p "What is the Client Secret? " clientsecret
read -r -e -p "What is the GUI username? " guiuser
read -r -e -p "And password of the user given above? " guipasswd
read -r -e -p "Whats the IP and Port number <ip:port>? " ipandport

curl=/usr/bin/curl
declare -p curlopt=()
curlopt+=( -k -X POST )
curlopt+=( -d "client_id='$clientid'" )
curlopt+=( -d "grant_type='$granttype'" )
curlopt+=( -d "client_secret='$clientsecret'" )
curlopt+=( -d "username='$guiuser'" )
curlopt+=( -d "password='$guipasswd'" )

$curl "${curlopt[@]}" "https://$ipandport/oauth/token"
```

**This is now my output**

```
+ curl=/usr/bin/curl
+ curlopt=()
+ declare -p curlopt
declare -a curlopt='()'
+ curlopt+=(-k -X POST)
+ curlopt+=(-d "client_id='$clientid'")
+ curlopt+=(-d "grant_type='$granttype'")
+ curlopt+=(-d "client_secret='$clientsecret'")
+ curlopt+=(-d "username='$guiuser'")
+ curlopt+=(-d "password='$guipasswd'")
+ /usr/bin/curl -k -X POST -d 'client_id='\''testing'\''' -d 'grant_type='\''testing'\''' -d 'client_secret='\''39f39834jf3m34'\''' -d 'username='\''test'\''' -d 'password='\''testing'\''' https://1.2.3.4:5678/oauth/token
```

Any idea how to get it to my expected output above?

Comment: Please fix your formatting, and reduce your question to a minimal example, with sample input and desired output.

Comment: Done - hope that is easier to understand

Comment: Remove `**` from your script and do `declare -p curlstring` to see what string you're getting. It is better to use a function or bash array to store command line.

Comment: Do you need the output like `"outout"` in **bold**?

Comment: @anubhava That threw an error, I want to use functions, but i'm still learning bash so want to keep it as straight forward as possible for now

Comment: @Aaron, please don't put code in comments -- the formatting sucks. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43326982/edit) if you have relevant things to add to your question.

Comment: @ghoti code edited, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question appears to include the line:

```
curlstring=$curlstring" client_id="$clientid"&grant_type="$granttype"&client_secret="$clientsecret"&username="$guiuser"&password="$guipasswd" https://"$ipandport"/oauth/token"
```

This is rather awkard, as you seem to be trying to expand your variables *outside* your double quotes. A better alternative would be to quote everything:

```
curlstring="$curlstring 'client_id=$clientid&grant_type=$granttype&client_secret=$clientsecret&username=$guiuser&password=$guipasswd' https://$ipandport/oauth/token"
```

Or even split the options into an array for easier management and reading:

```
curl=/usr/bin/curl
declare -a curlopt=()
curlopt+=( -k -X POST )
curlopt+=( -d "client_id='$clientid'" )
curlopt+=( -d "grant_type='$granttype'" )
curlopt+=( -d "client_secret='$clientsecret'" )
curlopt+=( -d "username='$guiuser'" )
curlopt+=( -d "password='$guipasswd'" )

$curl "${curlopt[@]}" "https://$ipandport/oauth/token"
```

Note that this suffers from a lack of input validation. What happens if the password contains a percent sign or ampersand?

Comment: This threw an error and the code being created in this array didn't not appear at the end?

Comment: What error did it throw? And what shell (or version of bash) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
"${curlopt[@]}"
```

generates a list of strings, one string for each array element.

If you want to concatenate all array elements to one string use this:

```
"${curlopt[*]}"
```